Scraping equations from arxiv
I have a software that parses and renders LaTeX formulas. I want to test its accuracy on a large dataset of equations extracted from arxiv papers. Arxiv offers an API to download papers in bulk and so, it is technically feasible to extract the code of all equations from all arxiv papers (or say a very large chunk of it).
Is it legal to make publically available a dataset of LaTeX equations generated in this way, as part of the test suite of my MIT-licensed software? Although it would be majorly inconvenient, I can include attributions to the many many authors in some form. In case the jurisdiction matters, I'm based in France but the papers of course from all over the globe.
What I (think I) learned from browsing the Internet and Legal SE:

Arxiv holds a distribution license, not the copyright.
Equations are not copyright-able, but their specific presentation may be. That would probably include the LaTeX code for the equation.
There is a notion of fair use, although I'm not sure whether it applies here.

Some references:

Technical Standards and Papers - Can the equations be copyrighted: https://law.stackexchange.com/a/62393/68725
When can you use images from arxiv papers for commercial purposes?: https://law.stackexchange.com/a/51905/68725


The problem you run into is with the use of the API, not copyright infringement
Let’s assume all of the equations are public domain, that is, there are no copyright issues at all. Your use of the API is still subject to the terms and conditions because they are a valid contract - they provide consideration (the service), you provide consideration (a promise to use it only in certain ways).
It doesn’t matter that you could legally copy out all the equations by hand; your use of the API means complying with the API’s terms. Now, I don’t know what those terms are and whether they allow such use - but you need to.

Thanks! The API terms are given here. I intend to honor rate limits and give acknowledgements to arxiv as required. So the one limiting clause is that I should not redistribute the e-print's source if the license does not permit it. So it seems I'm back to the copyright issue of the question: it is not clear to me whether redistributing the equations (part of the source) would be considered acceptable.

France doesn't have a "fair use" exception to copyright.
And in countries with fair use doctrines similar to US's I don't think it would apply. Extracting a small number of equations might fall within the "Amount and substantiality of the portion used" criterion, but extracting all the equations from a collection probably wouldn't.

France doesn't have a "fair use" exception to copyright true but that’s splitting hairs (see my answer on another question).
